# SQL Developing and Combining Loss Ratio

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

What I started with:

```
ID  Earned Premium  Losses  Expenses    Coverage
A22 100             15      5           Collision
A22 100             20      0           PIP
A22 100             5       0           Bodily Injury
A22 130             15      5           Collision
A22 130             20      0           PIP
A22 130             5       0           Bodily Injury
```

Because earned premium increases over time in order to get the latest information I used this below Query:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, Coverage order by Earned Premium desc) as seq
      from table t 
     ) t 
where seq = 1;
```

Now what I have:

```
ID  Earned Premium  Losses  Expenses    Coverage
A22 130             15      5           Collision
A22 130             20      0           PIP
A22 130             5       0           Bodily Injury
```

Now, what I must do is create a separate column which calculates my Loss Ratio per coverage and combined for the entire ID, the issue is I cannot merely sum my Earned Premium for the calculation because “130” is the total amount yet it shows up several times because of the coverage.

I want to sum all of my losses and expenses and calculate them against the 130 earned premium for the ID Loss Ratio and do a calculation by the row for my coverage loss ratio.

I’m pretty stumped here and don’t know the syntax either…

Loss Ratio = Losses + Expenses / Earned Premium

What I want:

```
ID  Earned Premium  Losses  Expenses    Coverage    Coverage Loss Ratio ID Loss Ratio
A22 130             15      5           Collision    15%                35%
A22 130             20      0           PIP          15%                35%
A22 130             5       0           Bodily Injury 4%                35%
```

Lengthy I know…

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE and subselect to get the total for figuring out the ID loss ratio. For the coverage loss ratio, you can just plug in your formula. You can change the fields to format as needed (multiply by 100, change to varchar to add %), but this shows the calculations you'll need.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, Coverage order by EarnedPremium desc) as seq
      from table t 
     ) t 
where seq = 1)
SELECT  *, 
        (Losses + Expenses)/EarnedPremium AS CoverageLossRatio, 
        (SELECT SUM(Losses + Expenses) FROM CTE a WHERE a.ID = b.ID) / EarnedPremium AS IDLossRatio
FROM CTE b;
```

Comment: Is this the actual syntax? i'm confused by your comment plus the syntax....

Comment: Yes, that would be the actual syntax, the comment is to kinda explain what it's doing a little bit, although, for better explanation: I took your query, made it a CTE and then I'm able to select from that CTE, and do a subselect from the CTE to roll up the total amounts for the ID. I did not do any formatting on the percentages, so it shows up as the decimal representation of the percentage.